# What would be the simplest way to automatically have the URL segment updated?

Tags: javascript, php, silverstripe

This question is about the URL Update feature when changing the value of a `Page` `Title` field. The behaviour is coded into *CMSMain.EditForm.js*.

[image]

I'm stripping down and customising the CMS to be usable by an absolute basic computer user or the negligent client, who will most likely skip pressing the *Update URL* button upon page name change. In these cases it would be very convenient if the `URLSegment` would be automatically updated.

Q: What would be the simplest way to automatically have the URL segment updated, IE **simulate the result** that would appear upon clicking the "Update URL" button, **after** changing the `Title` field?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could make an extension for SiteTree and include the function onBeforeWrite like this. This will make a change if they updated the Title and not the URL:

```
class AutoURLSync extends Extension {
    public function onBeforeWrite() {
        // If Title is changed, but URLSegment is not, 
        // then update the URLSegment here
        if($this->owner->isChanged('Title',2) && !$this->owner->isChanged('URLSegment',2)) {
            $this->owner->URLSegment = $this->owner->generateURLSegment($this->owner->Title);
        }
    }
}
```

Removing the "if" would mean it always is changed.

Add this in `_config/config.yml` to link up the extension:

```
SiteTree:
    extensions:
      - AutoURLSync
```

Comment: I changed the class name (`SiteTreeExtension` seems to already exist in core files), placed the if statement in brackets (also tried removing the if statement). I get an internal error on **Publish**

Comment: Whats the error?  is there still an error if you remove the "if"?

Comment: `Call to undefined method Extension::onBeforeWrite()` using a unique classname and removing the if statement (leaving inner part of the if statement untouched).

Comment: How about if it is "DataExtension" instead of "Extension" ?

Comment: Now I'm getting `Call to undefined method AutoURLSync::generateURLSegment()`. AutoURLSync is the classname I used instead of SiteTreeExtension. I think it should be `Extension` after all. I took a look in cms/code/model/SiteTreeExtension.php and couldnt find the `onBeforeWrite` function in there

Comment: face-palm - extensions use $this->owner-> instead of $this-> hopefully that will resolve it

Comment: I applied that, but the issue internal error was still showing. Removed `parent::onBeforeWrite();` and it works like a charm now. Cheers!

Comment: excellent :) now how did I leave that in there?  I must test these more before posting...